# Save Font from Font Dialog to My.Settings?

Tags: vb.net

How can I save a font to My.Settings, taking a font from a textbox. Can someone please give me a link to teach me how, I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Serialize` chosen font from Font Dialog and after that save font to `My.Settings`and 
here is some useful links:

[Save/Load Font Settings](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?624490-Save-Load-Font-Settings)

[VB.Net’s My.Settings and custom objects/classes; Part One: requirements for your class](http://cushen.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/vb-net%E2%80%99s-my-settings-and-custom-objectsclasses-part-one-requirements-for-your-class/)